# jplayer utf8 file name mp3 issue

Tags: php, jplayer

ok i manage to create my playlist by scanning my media folder (glob() php) function to build the playlist but currently  if the file is having chinese/japanese names will have issue while playing. for now a test my mp3 file name is this (note i am under linux hosting)

01-中国话.mp3 <-- file name

but during my view source code for the jplaylist

i saw this

title:"ÖÐ¹ú»°",
mp3:"playfile.php?file=01-�й���.mp3",
artist:"S.H.E"

as you can see i am having this 01-�й���.mp3 instead...

the way  i am getting the file name is something like this

```
       foreach(glob("{$directory}/*.{$extension}") as $file) {
            $ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($file);
            $songs = new Songs;
            $songs->setTitle($ThisFileInfo['tags_html']['id3v2']['title'][0]);
            $songs->setFileName($ThisFileInfo['filename']); // set file Name
            $songs->setArtist($ThisFileInfo['tags_html']['id3v2']['artist'][0]);
            $files[$file] = $songs;
        }
```

then output it like this

```
echo $comma.'{title:"'.$obj->getTitle().'",'.$plspacer.'mp3:"playfile.php?file='.$obj->getFileName().'",'.$plspacer.'artist:"'.$obj->getArtist().'"}';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to output a JavaScript object literal.  Try using JSON-encoding for this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'title' => $obj->getTitle(),
    'mp3' => 'playfile.php?file=' . urlencode($obj->getFileName()),
    'artist' => $obj->getArtist()
));
```

Comment: omg it works...thanks man, you are a life saver here...thank you very much...was finding a way to encode it but not successful instead by using json_encode would be the solution...

Comment: @user1217609 Glad you got it working!  Be sure to check the green check mark next to answers that are helpful to you.